# Why use returns(bool) in a transfer function?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, tokens, address.transfer

```
function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) public returns (bool) {

        require(balanceOf[msg.sender] >= _value);           
        require(balanceOf[_to] + _value >= balanceOf[_to]); 
        balanceOf[msg.sender] -= _value;                    
        balanceOf[_to] += _value;                           
        return true;
}
```

Do I need to use returns(bool)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's optional. There are pros and cons.

**Cons (against)**

- Gas cost. The contract is slightly larger, and each transaction has a slightly larger gas cost - to pack up the bool and return it in a slightly larger interface.

**Pros (for)**

- A Web3 client can run a transaction in dry-run mode or replay a transaction and inspect the returned value.
- A contract can guard processes with `require(theContract.transfer(addr,amount);`. This is readable and possibly less prone to developer error.
- It can reduce cognitive load on devs to use `bools` consistently. There are three (not two) possible outcomes a) yes b) no c) unacceptable. On the other hand, it can be confusing when some functions are expected to return something and others are silent. Inconsistency can lead to issues such as unchecked return values. Compiler-level warnings are getting better at catching possible oversights, so this argument is not as strong as it once was.

It is entirely possible (and common) to omit the return value. In that case, the function is only capable of returning (which is assumed success), or throwing an error (unacceptable, failed).

As Mr. Marx points out in the comment below, conformance to an interface standard is reason enough. When the interface says that it returns a bool, then that's what must do.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I want to add that if you're building an ERC20 contract, you MUST return a boolean. You're allowed to always return `true` (and revert on failures) as in the original code, but the return type must be `bool` to conform to the ERC20 standard. There have been real bugs due to tokens failing to do this: https://medium.com/coinmonks/missing-return-value-bug-at-least-130-tokens-affected-d67bf08521ca.

Comment: Great point. If the standard says you must, then you must.